# May I display the field from other table in the template in Django 1.10?

Tags: python, django

May I display the field from other table in the template in Django 1.10?

I have 3 tables as the following models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    no_of_monk = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Tbl_Province(models.Model):
        province_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
        province_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        geo_id = models.IntegerField()
        def __str__(self):
                return self.province_name

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Contact(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    confirm = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Tbl_Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order', 'province']
```

and I would like to display tbl_province.province_name where id=contact.id in the following template, is it possible?

```
{% for contact in group.contact_set.all %}
      <tr>
        <td width="10%" class="table-text"><div><strong>{{ forloop.counter0|mod:5|add:1 }}</strong></div></td>
        <td width="10%" class="table-text"><div>{{ forloop.counter }}</div></td>
        <td width="10%" class="table-text"><div>{{ contact.order }}</div></td>
        <td class="table-text"><div>{{ contact.name }}</div></td>
        {% if contact.province_id %}
            <td class="table-text"><div>{{ **Want to display tbl_province.province_name where id=contact.id here** }}</div></td>
        {% endif %}
        <td width="13%" class="table-text"><div><input type="text" name="ord" id="con-ord" class="form-control" value="{{ contact.amount|intcomma }}"></div></td>
        <td width="10%" class="table-text"><div>บาท</div></td>
        <td>
            <form action="{% url 'contribution:contactdel' contact.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" id="delete-group" class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i> Delete
            </button>
            </form>
        </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I would do the actual query to get tbl_province.province_name where id=contact.id in your view, and then pass that variable to the template when rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates don't have the access to the database, so they can't execute a query (and that's basically what you want)

However, I can see that you have a foreign key to `Tbl_Province` in `Contact` and you can use that instead - just write `{% contact.province.province_name %}` (if I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve)

If you need anything more exotic, you'll have to execute your query inside the view function, and then pass it to template context.

Comment: @Maicmi no problem, just remember that templates are used _for rendering only_ which means you can't manipulate data inside them. All database related logic must be done in views.py and models.py and the results must be passed to the template as context